# How do I select specific value using Php and preg_match using comma delimited?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match, explode

I am trying to select a certain numerical value that is separated by comma. The values are from a mysql db. I try to use explode the column but am not sure how to catch a certain value.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_array FROM values WHERE id='$id'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $get_id = $result['id_array'];
}

$exact = explode(",",$get_id);
```

Comment: ADD YOUR CURRETN CODE

Comment: well probably using the correct index for the exploded array, but without seeing more info its just a guess

Comment: Thank you Khaled. I guess I am lost on how to edit my own question.

Comment: You know I thank everyone for trying but if all you're going to do is critique instead of help then you're useless. I am asking for help with code. Not trolls trying to increase their status.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing a comma-separated list of values in column `id_array`, i.e.

```
12,17,44,13
```

After you've exploded the result you've got an array of the form

```
$exact is an array: 
(
    [0] => '12'
    [1] => '17'
    [2] => '44'
    [3] => '13'
)
```

Now you want to know if 17 is an element of this array. Right? You can do it with [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$check = in_array(17, $exact);   // true, if found as in my example.
// Please note, that it's important not to search in strict mode.
// Test with 100, not in list
$check = in_array(100, $exact)   // returns false
```

Maybe I misunderstood completely your problem. In this case please state with example data what your problem really is. What you've tried and where you got stuck.

PS: I wouldn't recommend storing comma separated lists in MySQL and it would be a great idea to drop the use of the mysql_* functions because they're deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.